# change attritube value based on other attribute value on select field

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code:

```
<select data-showinsummary="true" data-price="0">
     <option data-price="0" >OPTION 1</option>
     <option data-price="20">OPTION 2</option>
     <option data-price="10">OPTION 3</option>
</select>
```

when user select an option for example option 3 the data-price on select tag goes to 3 also.

By default on select tag, the data-showinsummary is "true" and data-price is "0" ,i can't change this.

what i'm trying to do is check if data-price on select tag is equal to "0" and if it is = 0 then i wanna change data-showinsummary from "true" to "false"

```
<select data-showinsummary="false" data-price="0">
```

i would like a solution using pure javascript or jquery. 
thank you very much :D

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What are the attributes `data-price` and `data-showinsummary`? These aren't standard HTML attributes; do they have some other significance we should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a onchange function.On change call a function and get the attribute value
Hope this snippet will be useful & change the attribute of select tag

```js
function updateValue() {
  if ($("#sel option:selected").data('price') == 0) {
    $("#sel").attr('data-showinsummary', false)
  } else {
    $("#sel").attr('data-showinsummary', true)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='sel' data-showinsummary="true" data-price="0" onchange='updateValue()'>
     <option data-price="0" >OPTION 1</option>
     <option data-price="20">OPTION 2</option>
     <option data-price="10">OPTION 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `var boo = $("#sel option:selected").data('price') == 0;    $("#sel").attr('data-showinsummary', boo)`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect" data-showinsummary="true" data-price="0">
     <option data-price="0" >OPTION 1</option>
     <option data-price="20">OPTION 2</option>
     <option data-price="10">OPTION 3</option>
</select>
```

and .js

```
   $(function(){
  $("#mySelect").change(function(e){
      if($('#mySelect').find(":selected").data('price') == 0){
      $(e.target).data('showinsummary' , 'false');  
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

give id "prices" to your select element like this:

```
<select id="prices" data-showinsummary="true" data-price="0">
    <option data-price="0" >OPTION 1</option>
    <option data-price="20">OPTION 2</option>
    <option data-price="10">OPTION 3</option>
</select>
```

and use this code for javascript part:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('prices').addEventListener('change', function() {
        var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

        this.setAttribute('data-price', selected.getAttribute('data-price'));

        if (selected.getAttribute('data-price') == 0) {
            this.setAttribute('data-showinsummary', false);
        } else {
            this.setAttribute('data-showinsummary', true);
        }
    });
}
```